# check if a pointer has some string c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am not good with c++ and I cannot find this anywhere, please apologize me if it is a bad question. I have a pointer and I want to know if some names store in this pointer begins with some specific string. As in python something like (maybe it is a bad example):

```
if 'Pre' in pointer_name:
```

This is what I have:

```
 double t = 0;
 for (size_t i =0; i < modules_.size(); ++i){
    if(module_[i].name() == "pre"){  // here is what I want to introduce the condition
        if (modules_[i].status() == 2){
            std::cout << module_[i].name() << "exists" << std::endl;
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: To clarify: you're using C-style strings instead of `std::string` for some incomprehensible reason, and you want to compare some substring of each one to a given string. Is that right?

Comment: (BTW, you don't "store" anything "in" a pointer other than a memory address.)

Comment: thanks for the correction.. I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Tomalek: Why the condescending attitude? C-style strings have several advantages over `std::string` (and some disadvantages of course). Neither is strictly better than the other, so don't be so quick to pass judgement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent of Python `'Pre' in string_name` is:

```
string_name.find("Pre") != std::string::npos // if using string

std::strstr(pointer_name, "Pre") // if using char*
```

The equivalent of Python `string_name.startswith('Pre')` ("begins with some specific string") is:

```
string_name.size() >= 3 && std::equal(string_name.begin(), string_name.begin() + 3, "Pre"); // if using string

string_name.find("Pre") == 0 // less efficient when it misses, but shorter

std::strncmp(pointer_name, "Pre", 3) == 0 // if using char*
```

In two of those cases, in practice, you might want to avoid using a literal `3` by measuring the string you're searching for.

Comment: Hi @steve-jessop and thanks for your answer, so the code should be like this? `for (size_t i =0; i < modules_.size(); ++i){  if (std::strstr(modules_[i].name(), "hltL1")){...`

Comment: That will do something for each element of `modules_` whose name contains `hltL1`, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Check [std::string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/), there are enough good examples. If you are using c-style string, use [strstr](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strstr/).

Comment: @Tony the op needs `some names store in this pointer begins with some specific string`, use comparison?

Comment: thanks @mu-qiao so, it should be something like this: `double t = 0;  size_t found;   for (size_t i =0; i < modules_.size(); ++i){      found=str.find("hltL1");   if(found!=module_[i].name()){`

Comment: @Alejandro no, if you are using std::string, find will return the position not the string. Check the link in my answer, there are examples so you can understand it easily.

Comment: @Alejandro: What is `str`? You don't have a `str`. And comparing `module_[i].name()` against a `size_t` isn't going to give you anything. Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: I check the page you told me (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and I was trying to implemented it.... :(

Answer (score 1):

If your `name` variable is of type `std::string` then you can use `name().compare("Pre") == 0` for string comparison.

EDIT: Seems I misunderstood the question, for contains you can use string find, as other said.

Using C style strings, `char *` is not recommended in C++. They are error prone.

Comment: That's equivalence, not containing.

Comment: @Dead: Yes, you're right, seems I misunderstood the OP's question.

Comment: `name().compare("Pre") == 0` can be written as `name() == "Pre"` or `"Pre" == name()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [algorithm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) header file to do most of things usually one liners in python.

In this case though it might be just easier to use [string find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) method .